# Does a registered stack apps application have to be a website?

Tags: discussion, api-key, registration, apps

If I've created an application that is not a website, can I still register it and get a key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure!  There are plenty of [apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app%2b-website?sort=votes) that are not websites.

Comment: Ok cool... just wondered because of the "Application Website" field on the registration page.

Comment: That field is if your app has a website with more info Eg sixtoeightapp.com

Comment: But you can't leave the Application Website field empty! What should I  use as URL?